# what does it mean by "LINQ to SQL is an ORM that allows the direct 1-1 mapping of a Microsoft SQL Server database to .NET classes"?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I was going through the difference between LINQ to SQL and entity framework when I came accross one point 
"LINQ to SQL is an object-relational mapping (ORM) framework that allows the direct 1-1 mapping of a Microsoft SQL Server database to .NET classes"

can anyone explain to me what is meant by "direct 1-1 mapping of a Microsoft SQL Server database to .NET classes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not necessarily a comprehensive answer, but it should clarify the most common case where this comes up.

If you have a many to many relationship between users and groups, LinqToSql will create 3 classes:  User, UserToGroup, Group.  Entity Framework will create 2 classes: User, Group.

It is awkward to most people to have a UserToGroup class (essentially a relational database construct to resolve a many to many relationship) exposed in the code model.  It's way more natural in code to navigate from a user to the groups the user is in, then to have to navigate through an extra, meaningless class.

This is generally seen as a "limitation" of LinqToSql.  I can't think of another .NET ORM with this "feature", every other one I know of supports the Entity Framework way.

Answer (score 1):

Every table and database in your schema will be represented by a .Net class in your ORM.

Comment: enttity framework works on the same basis, so if you have TableA you will have a class public class TableA {}